# Differences in partial dependence plots when using gbm.plot (dismo) and partial (pdp), why?

Tags: r, plot, partial, gbm

I am using boosted regression trees (gbm and dismo packages) to build habitat models and use partial dependence plots to look at the influence each predictor variable has on the response variable. I initially was using the gbm.plot function from the dismo package, but found the partial function from the pdp package which creates nicer looking plots however there are discrepancies between the two plots. See example images for latitude
[image: gbm.plot] 
[image: partial] 
The lines look similar but the y-axis is different on both plots, and I am wondering why. I tried looking at the functions using print() but it does not yield much for partial.

`final.model`: fitted BRT

`ceta_dd_final`: data used to build BRT

**Code for gbm.plot:**

```
gbm.plot(final.model, n.plots = 17, write.title = T,
  show.contrib = T, y.label = "fitted function")
```

**Code for partial:**

```
final.model %>%
  partial(pred.var = "lat", plot=FALSE, train = ceta_dd_final, n.trees = 2400) %>%
  plotPartial(smooth = TRUE, train = ceta_dd_final, rug = TRUE,
      lwd = 2, ylab = expression(f(lat)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `gbm.plot` uses the ordinary logit as the outcome for the plots, whereas `partial` uses a class-centered logit, this choice was made so that the y-axis has the same scale in binomial and multinomial models.